# strtotime making all dates have the current year

Tags: php

Working on a legacy application that is getting replaced at the end of next year. I am trying to modify how it writes some of the dates into the database and I'm just not familiar enough with PHP to figure out why it is doing this:

There is a date selector on the front-end. If you pick something like 1 Dec, 2019, it goes through jquery retaining that date, right before it is passed into the below function it is right, then it gets into the function and the `strtotime($str)` messes it up.

It converts 1 Dec, 2019 into `1543724340` which dropping into an UNIX timestamp shows it as 1 Dec, 2018.

How do I prevent this? I'm just trying to get the date for what the user sets in the calendar.

```
function str2date($str,$format="Y-m-d") {
    return date($format, strtotime($str));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the comma from the string with str_replace and strtotime can parse it correctly.

```
function str2date($str,$format="Y-m-d") {
    return date($format, strtotime(str_replace(",", "", $str)));
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ZP93WH

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to remove the , oder change the format. 
Just use DateTime:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("d M, Y", $date);
```

Then, if you need a Timestamp just use

```
$dateTime->getTimestamp();
```